# Angular 7+ component for building templates

Tags: angular, html-table

I am sorry if the title wording is a bit off, please feel free to correct it (I not a native English speaker).

Internet search is giving me totally irrelevant results - probably because I've got not clue how to word the question, but I'll try my best here.

I want to have a component in Angular 7+ which would display sort of an HTML table (it would be very simple, like a an Excel Spreadsheet) - with rows and columns. There would be a list of 10-15 variables (let's say these will be characters like 'A', 'B', 'C', etc.). I would like the user to be able to select where each character should end up the table.

Something of the sort:

Empty HTML view:

[image]

Then there would be characters for the user to select and add (or drag and drop):
A, B, C, D, etc.

This is what I want the final view to look like:

[image]

Then the table would be saved and next time it's being opened, the characters should be in the same spots. That table would then be used as a template and text would be inserted into appropriate 'cells' with certain characters.

Can someone please give me any leads on the best practices on how to implement this? Sorry if this might be too broad.

Comment: You are right, the question is too broad. Please see [ask].

Comment: This is indeed too broad. You can create the table with normal divs and set their size with `@angular/flex-layout`. Then use drag and drop feature from `@angular/cdk`.